# Sephardic Readers of Mishnah Berurah

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, mishnah-berurah

Do you know of any books that help Sephardic readers with the Mishnah Berurah (i.e. by telling them when Sephardic Poskim hold differently)?

Comment: Its even harder to find ones that tell you when Ashkenazi poskim hold differently

Comment: @DoubleAA Oz WeHadar just published one with Aruch Hashulhan and another company called Dirshu has a set on random lines from the M"B with quotes from other Poskim. There is also BeYishak Yekare and Oz Wehadar is working on another one like Metivta for Mishna Berura.

Comment: Also a note to the questioner: Harav Yishak Yosef advises that one just learn Mishna Berura and open up other Sefardi Poskim as he learns but the Ish Masliah version is much simpler and more useful.

Comment: This may not be what you are looking for, but it is a very interesting sefer by Avraham Chaim Noeh, a Lubavitcher Chasid who was the secretary of Rabbi Yosef Chaim Zonnenfeld (Ashkenazi Rabbi of Jerusalem), it is a kitzur shulchan aruch style sefer based on Egyptian minhagim, and with a Judeo-Arabic translation(!).http://www.hebrewbooks.org/35286

Answer (score 4):

The Ish Masliah version would probably be what you're looking for. It brings when the Kaf HaHaim disagrees with the M"B, when Hacham Ovadia and also Rav Moshe Lewi disagree as well. As well as many other great features

[Here](http://www.seforimcenter.com/product.asp?P_ID=6604&strPageHistory=search&strKeywords=ish,matzliach&numPageStartPosition=1&strSearchCriteria=all&PT_ID=all) it is online for around 90$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new [Mishna Berura Tiferes Hamizrach](http://zbermanbooks.com/product-54117.html) - with all the Sefardi Poskim - published by Zundel Berman. So far it is only available on Hilchos Chanuka from volume 6, however the author is planning on doing the entire Mishna Berura over the next few years.

Can be purchased at [Hamefitzim](http://www.hamefitzim.co.il/Product.aspx?productid=3803) or [Mekor Judaica](http://mekorjudaica.com/Mishnah-Berurah-Tiferet-HaMizrach--Halachot-of-Chanukah.aspx).

Comment: It has all the Sefardi poskim? Sounds massive.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Check it out and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

And yet another two
1."Tiferet" distributed by [Feldheim](http://www.feldheim.com/mishnah-berurah-tiferet.html)
2. Ohr Hamizrach by [Machon Yerushalayim](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/36145499/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%97-%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7-%D7%90---%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D)